# Javascript contains - checking multiple values

Tags: javascript

I have just noticed my `.contains` was not working when I had multiple values (comma separated).

```
var checkMenu = document.getElementById('primary-header');
var primaryHeaderClasses = checkMenu.classList;

switch( true ) {
case primaryHeaderClasses.contains('primary-header--center-logo-center-menu, primary-header--left-logo-secondary-menu'):
```

If I remove the second class in the contains, it works fine:

```
switch( true ) {
case primaryHeaderClasses.contains('primary-header--center-logo-center-menu'):
```

What's the correct method to do the `.contains` to check for one or more classes?

Comment: Do you want it to pass if either class is present, or only if both? The fact you're using `case` here suggests you're doing something *very* wrong.

Comment: Looking to do X if either class is present.

Comment: You can create a list of classes and iterate through them using contains. Contains doesnt work with multiple classes.

Comment: There is no way to do a `contains` with multiple values. You can only run it multiple times and check if each value exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to do X if either class is present, why don't you do this?

```
if(primaryHeaderClasses.contains('primary-header--center-logo-center-menu') || primaryHeaderClasses.contains('primary-header--left-logo-secondary-menu')) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

By adding `||` you are telling "if this or this is true, do X".

If you have a good level at JQuery and JavaScript you can use this form:

```
if($("document:contains('primary-header--center-logo-center-menu'), document:contains('primary-header--left-logo-secondary-menu')")) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contains does not support multiple values, you should make a loop and check the values for each entry. As far as I know this is the only way you could do this.

Comment: This is part of a `switch`, not a variable declaration. `const something.someMethod()` doesn't really make sense anyway.

Comment: Nope. The switch was missing in the snippet, so I thought OP was making a typo :)

Comment: The `swich` was missing but `const` still didn't fit. It made a lot more sense to be a `case` belonging to a `switch`. The first paragraph of your answer doesn't make sense either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.some()` to do this.

Essentially what `.some()` does is that it checks every element of the array using a function and if any element returns true then it returns true. Otherwise, it returns false.

In your case you want to use

```
['primary-header--center-logo-center-menu', 'primary-header--left-logo-secondary-menu'].some(e => primaryheaderClasses.contains(e))
```

and this will only return true if primaryHeaderClasses contains any element `e` of the array.

This also works in all browsers 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)